# What is "DEDENT" in Python reference?

Tags: python

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-suite

> > suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ **DEDENT**

I can understand the 'DEDENT' word as "Dedent Region" in [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html)(`Ctrl+[`), But I can't understand the 'detent' appear in [python reference document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-suite), is "DEDENT" one special character?

Comment: AFAIK dedent simply means outdent (opposite of indent).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not a character per se - it is a token that represents the fact that the current line is indented by less spaces than the one before.

So for example the code:

```
foo
if bar:
  bay
baz
```

would be tokenized as `ID(foo), NEWLINE, IF, ID(bar), COLON, NEWLINE, INDENT, ID(bay), NEWLINE, DEDENT, ID(baz)`.

Comment: If only there were some standard existing term for this so that Python didn't need to invent one.  Something that meant the opposite of INdent...something like...hm. Something where you reverse the INdentation and move it OUTwards.  I feel like there should be such a thing, but I can't quite come up with it.  *grumble, grumble* </dry humor>